# PyAudio.open, how to use?

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to make a pyaudio input stream but can't figure out how to make it.
What I did is:

```
a = pyaudio.PyAudio()
```

Then tried to call a.open() but I don't know the arguments I should type in. It asks me to check Stream.**init** for a reference, but I don't know what a PA_MANAGER is and the documentation isn't useful at all about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could start by modfying some of the [examples](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#examples)?